# Rethrowing previous exception inside ContinueWith

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

###Intro

After puzzling over my code for a while, I discovered that exceptions don't *necessarily* propagate through `ContinueWith`:

```
int zeroOrOne = 1;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 3 / zeroOrOne)
    .ContinueWith(t => t.Result * 2)
    .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Result))
    .ContinueWith(_ => SetBusy(false))
    .LogExceptions();
```

In this example, the `SetBusy` line 'resets' the chain of exceptions, so the divide by zero exception isn't seen and subsequently blows up in my face with *"A Task's exception(s) were not observed..."*

So... I wrote myself a little extension method (with tons of different overloads, but basically all doing this):

```
public static Task ContinueWithEx(this Task task, Action<Task> continuation)
{
     return task.ContinueWith(t =>
     {
         if(t.IsFaulted) throw t.Exception;
         continuation(t);
     });
}
```

Searching around a bit more, I came across [this](http://www.rizalalmashoor.com/blog/exception-handling-wrappers-for-taskcontinuewith/) blog post, where he proposes a similar solution, but using a TaskCompletionSource, which (paraphrased) looks like this:

```
public static Task ContinueWithEx(this Task task, Action<Task> continuation)
{
     var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
     task.ContinueWith(t =>
     {
         if(t.IsFaulted) tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception);
         continuation(t);
         tcs.TrySetResult(default(object));
     });
     return tcs.Task;
}
```

###Question
Are these two versions strictly equivalent? Or is there a subtle difference between `throw t.Exception` and `tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception)`?

Also, does the fact that there's apparently only one other person on the whole internet who's done this indicate that I'm missing the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: Why are you even having such a chain in the first place? Why can't you execute all of the actions as a single `Task`?

Comment: @svick, eh, good question. Because I hadn't even thought of doing it that way? :) That aside, in my real code, the last element (`SetBusy`) needs to be run on a different scheduler. I'll give it a try anyway, just to see.

Comment: @svick, what's not clear in my example code is that each `ContinueWith` contains a task. If I try to line these up separately inside a parent task, it works, but it's a bit ugly, because I have to explicitly `Wait` for each one before continuing with the next - otherwise I have to fallback to ContinuingWith again, and have just nested the problem. I think.

Comment: A related GiHub issue: [Then or ContinueWithResult extension method for Task](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58692)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The difference between the two is subtle.  In the first example, you are throwing the exception returned from the task.  This will trigger the normal exception throwing and catching in the CLR, the `ContinueWith` will catch and wrap it and pass it to the next task in the chain.

In the second you are calling `TrySetException` which will still wrap the exception and pass it to the next task in the chain, but does not trigger any try/catch logic.

The end result after one `ContinueWithEx` is `AggregateException(AggregateException(DivideByZeroException))`.  The only difference I see is that the inner AggregateException has a stack trace set in the first example (because it was thrown) and no stack trace in the second example.

Neither is likely to be significantly faster than the other, but I would personally prefer the second to avoid unneeded throws.

I have done something like this where the continuation returned a result.  I called it `Select`, handled cases of the previous task being cancelled, provided overloads to modify the exception instead of or in addition to the result, and used the `ExecuteSynchronously` option.  When the continuation would itself return a Task, I called that `Then` instead based on the code from [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/11/21/10094564.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give this detailed explanation.

Comment: I also changed to `Then`, inspired by the article linked in my question. But then I noticed that `Then` already exists and returns a 'Plan', so I figured that might be a bit too confusing.