# How to avoid over-nesting exceptions when using Task continuations

Tags: c#, exception, task

In some part of my code I have this:

```
task.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message
```

Which seems wrong to me. Is it normal?

The origin of this is when I do a ContinueWith to a task, but in the ContinueWith y throw again the exception if it wasn't the success case, like this:

```
t.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Exception != null) throw task.Exception;
                // do something with task.Result
            });
```

I've tried to do the continuation only on the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion` case, but then the exception is not propagated and the task is treated as canceled instead of faulted.

Comment: First of, you shouldn't be rethrowing exceptions like that. The keyword `throw` will effectively rewrite the exception's stacktrace, losing valuable information about the original context from where the exception was thrown.

Comment: Second, can you not use the `async/await` idiom?

Comment: hmmm let me see if that propagates the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to simply use the async/await idiom.

```
try
{
    await SomeTask();
    await SomeOtherTask();
    SomeSynchronousProcessing();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

This is the same as chaining a series of tasks and, if one fails, the others are skipped.

Comment: Yup, that helped. Now I only have to go through 1 InnerException, which i guess is okay.

Comment: Just for curiosity (and a better understanding of .Net tasks) do you know how to get the same behavior using ContinueWith ?

Comment: @LayGonzález You could use one of the [`TaskContinuationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), for example `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` or `NotOnFaulted`.

Comment: @LayGonzález This works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nFxOTF but it's a bit too..... verbose. Maybe there's a shorter way.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839959/rethrowing-previous-exception-inside-continuewith